# gazebo_ros_pkgs is installed, but directory is empty

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this vid tutorial on YouTube on controlling joints. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qCh-p-hzCM. After I typed out the URDF, config and launch files, I ran the roslaunch command from the terminal. I get the following output.

```
... logging to /home/varun/.ros/log/2244837a-447c-11e8-a7c2-7c67a2be706c/roslaunch-varun-5577-22296.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://varun-5577:46733/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21
 * /simple_model/ball_joint_position_controller/joint: ball_joint
 * /simple_model/ball_joint_position_controller/pid/d: 0
 * /simple_model/ball_joint_position_controller/pid/i: 0
 * /simple_model/ball_joint_position_controller/pid/p: 1.0
 * /simple_model/ball_joint_position_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /simple_model/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 20
 * /simple_model/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...

NODES
  /simple_model/
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    urdf_spawner (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [22308]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2244837a-447c-11e8-a7c2-7c67a2be706c
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [22321]
started core service [/rosout]
process[urdf_spawner-2]: started with pid [22329]
process[simple_model/controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [22336]
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [22338]
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1524216058.478740] Loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1524216058.481209] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[WARN] [WallTime: 1524216088.428033] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[simple_model/controller_spawner-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/varun/.ros/log/2244837a-447c-11e8-a7c2-7c67a2be706c/simple_model-controller_spawner-3*.log
^C[robot_state_publisher-4] killing on exit
[urdf_spawner-2] killing on exit
```

I get this error saying 'Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.' Many people who experience this error had forgotten to install gazebo_ros_pkgs, but I had already installed it today. The urdf file searches for a file called libgazebo_ros_control.so, so I thought it would exist inside the gazebo_ros_control folder in gazebo_ros_pkgs. But to my surprise, gazebo_ros_pkgs was empty, except for the existence of a launch.xml file. Repeated attempts to remove and reinstall the packages were in vain, as it would still remain empty. I think the missing contents of this folder are the problem, but I haven't seen any error where it states that libgazebo_ros_control.so is missing. I find this very strange. What could be the problem?

I'm running ROS Indigo, Gazebo 7 on 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289192/gazebo_ros_pkgs-is-installed,-but-directory-is-empty/) by [varunvp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33790/varunvp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, [gazebo_ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_control) is not a dependency of [gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs), but needs to be installed separately.

After installing that, the library should be located in `/opt/ros/$distro/lib`.

If you feel this is a problem with the video you watched, then I suggest contacting the author(s) as it would be something that needs to be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1